# Maven Assembly: DependencySet or ModuleSet

Tags: java, maven, maven-assembly-plugin

I have a multi-module project:

*Assembly-Project

--------- Module1

--------- Module2*

I want to collect the jars of the modules in my assemby (zip).
What is the best way to archive that? Using moduleSets or dependenySets or both? I simply want to put the module jars into a lib folder in the zip and all the modules are in the modules section of the assembly project, cause I want to build them before assembling the zip.

Any hints? Tipps? Best practices?

Best,
Jan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how I've done it for the SoftSmithy project:

https://github.com/SoftSmithy/softsmithy-lib/blob/3d4cdaa74febe37bc58420e25dd340c0d0d1cd17/src/main/assembly/dist.xml

Here is the generated zip file: http://sourceforge.net/projects/softsmithy/files/softsmithy/v0.3/

Here is the corresponding multi-module pom: 
https://github.com/SoftSmithy/softsmithy-lib/blob/3d4cdaa74febe37bc58420e25dd340c0d0d1cd17/pom.xml

(I used moduleSets.)

Comment: That look great and helps a lot. One question: Is it possible to describe (in the assembly desriptor) s/t like that:  "Include all module artifact" without creating a moduleSet entry for all modules? I ask because if you add a new module, you have to adapt the assembly descripor as well, right?